# Algorithm for finding unopened html/jsp tags using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out an effective algorithm to parse a .jsp file, and find all occurrences of closing tags that have no opening counterpart.

For example, with the following jsp, the program should be able to pick up the `</html:select>` tag above `</body>`

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <html:select>
        <html:options></html:options>
        <html:options></html:options>
    </html:select>
    </html:select>
</body>
</html>
```

I was initially thinking of using Stack, pushing every time a tag is opened, then popping once a closing tag `</` is read, but this won't work because I would need to know which tag gets left behind in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a `Stack` sounds like a good idea, however, HTML is not a strict as XML, and some tags, like `meta` in your example, do not need to be closed. You can however use a table of the tags that don't need a closing tag.
The algorithm would be: each opening tag is pushed on the stack, unless it is a tag that do not need a closing tag. When a closing tag is found, if it matches the element at the top of the stack, all is good, you can pop it from the stack and continue. Otherwise, it's either that there is an extra closing tag, as in your example, or that some other tag was open, and the corresponding closing tag is missing. You can try to walk up the stack until you find the tag that you're looking for, but you would have to decide how many closing tags you can tolerate to skip.